# How can I add an all option to a dropdown to query all categories in yii2?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

So I have created a simple search form, and created the query within my controller (I am aware this isn't the best way to do it and should be done in my model/search model however for the time being it will do).

I was wondering how can I add an option to my form within the two dropdown with the label All which if passed will mean that that part of the query isn't applied.

Below is my view

```
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'home-search','method' => 'post', 'action' => Url::to(['productitem/search'])]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($productitem, 'name')->textInput(array('placeholder' => 'What are you looking for?'))->label(false) ?>

    <?= $form->field($productitem, 'brand_id')->dropDownList(

        ArrayHelper::map(ProductBrand::find()->all(),'id','name'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Brand']

    )->label(false) ?>

    <?= $form->field($productitem, 'category_id')->dropDownList(

        ArrayHelper::map(ProductCategory::find()->all(),'id','name'),
        ['prompt'=>'Select Department']

    )->label(false) ?>

    <div class="form-group search-button">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="login-button">Search <i class="fa fa-lg fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></button>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Below is my controller/query

```
    public function actionSearch()
{
    $query = ProductItem::find()
    ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $_POST['ProductItem']['name']])
    ->andFilterWhere(['in', 'brand_id', $_POST['ProductItem']['brand_id']])
    ->andFilterWhere(['in', 'category_id', $_POST['ProductItem']['category_id']]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query
    ]);

    return $this->render('search', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be in fact to have the search function in your model. That way, if a department or brand is not selected, it will return all the records.

Comment: @JoeMiller if I put the search function in my model does it need be adapted, I also just wanted to have an option in my dropdown that said "All" as the placeholder/prompt says select category.

Comment: If you just change the prompt so it says something like "Search all departments", it will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will offer some reference.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'categoryid1')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'id' => 'categoryid1',
    'name' => 'categoryid1',
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Category::getCategoryByPid(0), 'id', 'name'),
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'choose first',
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
])->label('first') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'categoryid2')->widget(DepDrop::className(), [
    'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
    'id' => 'categoryid2',
    'name' => 'categoryid2',
    'data' => $model->categoryid1 ? ArrayHelper::map(Category::getCategoryByPid($model->categoryid1), 'id', 'name') : [],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'depends' => ['product-categoryid1'],
        'placeholder' => 'choose second',
        'url' => Url::to(['/category/second'])
    ]
])->label('second'); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'categoryid')->widget(DepDrop::className(), [
    'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2,
    'data' => $model->categoryid2 ? ArrayHelper::map(Category::getCategoryByPid($model->categoryid2), 'id', 'name') : [],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'depends' => ['product-categoryid1', 'product-categoryid2'],
        'placeholder' => 'third',
        'url' => Url::to(['/category/third'])
    ]
])->label('third'); ?>
```